# ImportError: No module named class_vis

Tags: python, python-2.7

Have I missed the boat on this? I've scoured the net for information on installing a package, notably prettyPicture, but there is nothing out there. Is this not in use anymore?

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from studentRegression import studentReg
from class_vis import prettyPicture, output_image

from ages_networths import ageNetWorthData

ages_train, ages_test, net_worths_train, net_worths_test = ageNetWorthData()

reg=studentReg(ages_train,net_worths_train)

plt.clf()
plt.scatter(ages_train,net_worths_train,color="b",label="train data")
plt.scatter(ages_test, net_worths_test, color='r', label="test data")
plt.plot(ages_test, reg.predict(ages_test), color="black")
plt.legent(loc=2)
plt.xlabel("ages")
plt.ylabel("net worths")

plt.savefig("test.png")
output_image("test.png", "png", open("test.png", "rb").read())
```

Error Message:

> ```
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-10-7e6ab2d3ca3d> in <module>()
>       5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>       6 #from studentRegression import studentReg
> ----> 7 from class_vis import prettyPicture, output_image
>       8 
>       9 from ages_networths import ageNetWorthData
>
> ImportError: No module named class_vis
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_vis.py` is available [here](https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects/blob/master/choose_your_own/class_vis.py).  It is from:

### ud120-projects

#### Starter project code for students taking Udacity ud120

Comment: Thanks. I did see this. However, where and how do I store this so that it works with "from class_vis import prettyPicture, output_image"? Or, is there another way to implement this besides placing the code in my program (with a couple changes of course)? Thanks!

Comment: Just copy the file to same directory as your script.

Comment: Thanks. I did save it to the same directory, originally, but saved it as class_vis.py.ipynb. :/